# newView and bindView do not get called

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I am trying to setup a custom `CursorAdapter` inside a `ListActivity` with a `CursorLoader`, but unfortunately the overridden methods `newView` and `bindView` never get called. I can only see the `ListView` items with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I have tried everything to no effect. Here's my code:

My ListActivity:

```
public class BgListActivity extends ListActivity implements 
LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private static String TAG = "BG-ListActivity";
private BgAdapter mCursorAdapter;
//private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getListView();
    mCursorAdapter = new BgAdapter(this, null, 0);
    setListAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    /*adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bg_list, null,
            new String [] {BgContract.DATE, BgContract.TIME_OF_DAY, 
            BgContract.BG_MEASUREMENT}, new int [] {R.id.date_textview, 
            R.id.timeofday_textview, R.id.measurement_textview}, 0);*/
    Log.i(TAG, "BgAdapter and loader initialized");
}

@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onCreateLoader() callback method");

    final String [] PROJECTION = new String [] {BgContract._ID, BgContract.DATE, 
            BgContract.TIME_OF_DAY, BgContract.BG_MEASUREMENT};

    return new CursorLoader(this, BgContract.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,
            null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> newLoader, Cursor newCursor) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onLoadFinished() callback method");
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(newCursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> newLoader) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onLoaderReset() callback method");
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

}

My CursorAdapter:

```
public class BgAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
private static LayoutInflater sLayoutInflater = null;
private Context mContext;

public BgAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
    super(context, cursor, flags);
    mContext = context;
    sLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    Log.i(TAG,"BgAdapter constructor created " + mContext.toString() + 
            " " + sLayoutInflater.toString() + " cursor == null? " + (cursor==null));
}
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.date.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.
            getColumnIndex(BgContract.DATE)));
    holder.timeOfDay.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.
            getColumnIndex(BgContract.TIME_OF_DAY)));
    holder.bGMeasurement.setText(Float.toString(cursor.getFloat(cursor.
            getColumnIndex(BgContract.BG_MEASUREMENT))));
    Log.i(TAG, "Views loaded");
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View newView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    newView = sLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bg_list, parent,
            false);
    holder.date = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.date_textview);
    holder.timeOfDay = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.timeofday_textview);
    holder.bGMeasurement = (TextView) newView.findViewById(R.id.measurement_textview);

    newView.setTag(holder);
    Log.i(TAG, "NewView setup!");

    return newView;

}
```

}

And here is the xml for the row items:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timeofday_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="middle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/measurement_textview"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Any suggestions before I revert to the `SimpleCursorAdapter` solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you need a custom CursorAdapter for?  why not to use a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: Are your `LoaderCallbacks` being called? Did you try putting a breakpoint?

Comment: Yes,the LoaderCallbacks get called. First onCreateLoader and then onLoaderFinished.

Comment: is the `Cursor` you get back from `onLoadFinished()` empty?

Comment: @pskink I want to customize the rows that's why

Comment: @Emmanuel It's position is -1. I'm calling the ListActivity through an intent by pressing a button from the main activity

Comment: you can customize it using SimpleCursorAdapter too

Comment: @pskink The ListView is only displayed using an instance of SimpleCursorAdapter. There is no way I can get a custom CursorAdapter working.

Comment: So i am asking: why do you need a custom CursorAdapter CA?  why not to use SCA?

Comment: @ pskink: I just wanted to customize the rows of the ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of head scratching I finally solved the mystery:
In my custom CursorAdapter implementation I had the following overriden method:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mBgRecords.size();
}
```

where mBgRecords is an ArrayList of records, which I suppose was null at the time the cursor was bound to the adapter. So, I replaced it with the following:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (getCursor() == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    return super.getCount();
}
```

and everything is back to normal

Comment: When we call `super.getCount()` it makes the null check itself. So its not neccessary add it.

getCount() in CursorAdapter.java:

`public int getCount() {
        if (mDataValid && mCursor != null) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }`